# CakePHP simple authentication tutorial is not working

Tags: cakephp, authentication, controller, cakephp-2.4

I'm new to CakePHP. I'm trying [the Cake cookbook tutorial of simple authentication](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) with CakePHP 2.4.1.
I'm always getting "Invalid username or password, try again" although I typed the correct username and password.

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}
```

According to [the AuthComponent API](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-AuthComponent.html#_login), if the parameter to `Auth->login()` is empty or not specified, the request will be used to identify a user.
The debugging query output shows

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`role`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified` 
FROM `cake_dvdcatalog`.`users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`username` = 'admin' LIMIT 1
```

Here is my User model:

```
// app/Model/User.php
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

class User extends AppModel {

    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A username is required'
            )
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A password is required'
            )
        ),
        'role' => array(
            'valid' => array(
                'rule' => array('inList', array('admin', 'author')),
                'message' => 'Please enter a valid role',
                'allowEmpty' => false
            )
        )
    );

    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code for your user model?

Comment: Try to debug $this->Auth->login() method. An encrypted password should be the same as in database.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check your Encrypted Password,
Cakephp By Default use SHA1, So it's beter to create a user using Cakephp with SHA1 password, Add **beforesave** method in user model to encrypt password

Answer (score 0):

The auth component goes in the controller not the model. Try removing this from the model:

`App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');`

And adding it to the the AppController. Also add this to the app controller:

`public $components = array('Auth');`

You may need some additional configuration if you want to use non-default settings.

Comment: According to the cookbook tutorial, `$components = array('Auth');` is already defined in `AppController`.

Comment: You need to 1) make sure the actual AppController file includes the component. 2) the original post above shows that you are loading the auth component in the user model, which is incorrect. Components correspond to controllers, not models.

Comment: The cookbook tutorial itself shows that the Auth component is loaded both in the user model and AppController. Anyway, I removed it from the model.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you've missed out something, please make sure you have followed the same tutorial for CakePHP 2.x http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html.

Please create user on `http://localhost/application_name/users/add` after all configuration done and try with such user. It's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have the following item in the $components array within the 'AppController.php' file:

```
'authenticate' => array(
   'Form' => array(
       'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
   )
)
```